# Error 401 loading XML with XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

My application (desktop c# forms) read a XML file to insert data in a database.

I am getting this error (remote server returned error 401 unauthorized), when executing the .Load method of a XmlDocument object.

```
 var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
 var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.Load(stream);
 ...
```

Only some machines, in production infrastructure are getting this error. This could be a missing permission?

Comment: Sure sounds like it.  Since it's a desktop application, is it running under the user's credentials or a different account?  To put it another way, do different users have the problem, or is solely based on certain machines?

Comment: I'm getting this problem with some users and some workstation machines. I just tried in a server machine in my client and works. It is a problem in the users machines.

Comment: Does the stack trace in the users machines error have any details other than the 401?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `.Credentials` property of the `XmlResolver` for the `XmlDocument`.

```
 XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
 resolver.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

 var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
 var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.XmlResolver = resolver;  // Set the resolver.
 xmlDoc.Load(stream);
```

Docs: [system.xml.xmldocument.xmlresolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.xmlresolver.aspx)

Comment: Oh. Where are you loading the file from? Local folder or network folder?

Comment: From local folders. In this case, from D:\somedirectory partition.